# Problem with dokka CLI - "Exiting Generation: Nothing to document"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I'm trying to generate documentation for my kotlin code. Some of my classes and functions have KDOC comments.

I tried to run dokka from the CLI like this:

> java -jar dokka-cli-1.4.20.jar

And the result was:

> WARN: Dokka 1.4.* is an alpha project PROGRESS: Initializing plugins
> Loaded plugins: [] Loaded: [
>
> ] Suppressed: [
>
> ] PROGRESS: Validity check PROGRESS: Creating documentation models
> PROGRESS: Exiting Generation: Nothing to document PROGRESS:
>
> === TIME MEASUREMENT ===
>
> ```
>                Initializing plugins: 26
>                      Validity check: 32
>       Creating documentation models: 28 
>       Exiting Generation: Nothing to document:  1
> ```

I have tried to execute this:

- in the project's folder.
- in the src folder
- in the first src sub-folder that has .kt files

The result was similar for all runs.

Any ideias on how to solve this? Thanks.